# LocalDateTime cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, variables

just want to add all the variables in a "Performer-object" an add it to a list afterwards. So i have the class "Performer" and if i want to initialize a object would be like:

```
Performer a = new Performer("Red Hot Chili Peppers", Kind.Punk, LocalDateTime.of(2015, 07, 17, 14, 00), LocalDateTime.of(2015, 07, 17, 16, 00) , Stage.MainStage)
```

Also have a method addBand with the part:

```
System.out.println("End:");
  sc.nextLine();
  sc.findInLine("(\\d\\d)\\.(\\d\\d)\\. (\\d\\d):(\\d\\d)");
  try{
   MatchResult mr =sc.match();
   int month = Integer.parseInt(mr.group(2));
            int day = Integer.parseInt(mr.group(1));
            int hour = Integer.parseInt(mr.group(3));
            int minute = Integer.parseInt(mr.group(4));

            LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.of(year, month, day, hour, minute);
            //System.out.println(end);
           } catch (IllegalStateException e) 
  {
            System.err.println("Invalid input!");
        }

  Performer performer = new Performer(bandname, kind, start, end , stage);

  listperformer.add(performer);
  return listperformer;
```

Turns out, that eclipse says: "end cannot be resolved to a varialbe"
Same code for end i do have for start, so same error here.
I have no clue wheres the problem.

Comment: please post the code where you declare "start" and "end". in your case the method header I think.

Comment: Ok here is the problem.
I think it is already declared with the line:                                                           

LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.of(year, month, day, hour, minute);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

end variable is declare inside the try block so it can't be used outside the try block.

declare it outside of try block and initialize this inside try block.

```
LocalDateTime end = null;
try{
 MatchResult mr =sc.match();
 int month = Integer.parseInt(mr.group(2));
 int day = Integer.parseInt(mr.group(1));
 int hour = Integer.parseInt(mr.group(3));
 int minute = Integer.parseInt(mr.group(4));
 end = LocalDateTime.of(year, month, day, hour, minute);
 //System.out.println(end);
} catch (IllegalStateException e){
   System.err.println("Invalid input!");
}

Performer performer = new Performer(bandname, kind, start, end , stage);

listperformer.add(performer);
return listperformer;
```

Comment: perfect, now it works, wasn't clear to me how try-catch works! One thing more: as Performer is an other class, i don't know how it works to call the constructor of an other class, can you help me out with this issue too please?

Answer (score 0):

You declare the `end` variable inside the `try` block, but you access it outside the block. This give you the error that the `end` variable cannot be resolved.

The other thing is, I also didn't see where you define the `year` variable. This also will give you the same error.